# How to make a with_column become the first column w/o selecting all columns

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I have a simple df

```
df=pl.DataFrame(
{
    "date":["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"],
    "hroff":[5,2],
    "minoff":[1,2]
}).with_column(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

If I want to add a column I can do `df=df.with_column(pl.lit('abc').alias('newcolumn'))`

but if I want that new column to be first is there a direct way to do that other than having to add `.select(['newcolumn','date','hroff','minoff'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.select([
    pl.lit('abc').alias('newcolumn'),
    pl.all()
])
```